# Calling DataWindow Update() method when it contains a computed colum - PowerBuilder 11.5

Tags: powerbuilder, calculated-columns, datawindow

I'm rather new to PB, so I'm sure this is not the most insightful or brilliant question. I want to know if it's possible to make a column in a DataWindow updatable when that column is a computed column. For example, say I have a computed column that joins the city, state, and zip of an employee:

```
COMPUTE(emp.city + ' ' + emp.state + ', ' + emp.zip)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. When it issues the Update SQL, it would have no idea which columns to update.